# ¿Cómo deshacer 'git add' antes de confirmar?

Tags: git, git-add

Tengo una duda al hacer `git add .` después reviso con `git status` y me aparecen todos los archivos agregados hay forma de deshacer esto, osea volver a tenerlos todos como antes del `git add .`

¿Hay forma de retornar o si puedo seleccionar un solo archivo para des agregarlo?

muchas gracias.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Para deshacer el *staging* que hizo el `git add .`, puedes hacer:

```
git reset
```

Verás que los archivos no cambian, es solo que deshaces el *staging* en preparación para el commit.

---

Si, en vez de querer deshacer todo lo que hizo `git add .`, mas bien quieres hacerle *unstage* a un solo archivo, entonces puedes usar el mismo comando, pero especificando el archivo en particular:

```
git reset HEAD nombre_del_archivo.ext
```